# iOS Auto Layout conundrum - fails on initial view but works after rotating the phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new to iOS programming and working on a legacy app that is written in Objective C and C++. It has not had constraints up until now and I am tasked with fixing a bug that everyone here agrees is best solved with constraints and auto layout. None of the screens have been built with Interface Builder and switching to Interface builder is outside the scope of my current task.

My problem as stated in the subject is that I have a screen which spews an error when it is first opened:

```
2017-06-09 07:35:58.474149 Mobile[2132:1766896] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
   Try this: 
       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1899dd30 V:|-(50)-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:0x17ba9a00]   (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:0x17f88200 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1899e310 V:|-(0)-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:0x17ba9a00]   (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:0x17f88200 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1899dd30 V:|-(50)-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:0x17ba9a00]   (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:0x17f88200 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

If I ignore this and simply rotate the screen to landscape, I get no more error messages and the screen displays properly. I can then rotate back to portrait and the screen is still displayed correctly with no error messages.

I am convinced that this is an issue with my constraints but I cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

```
UIScrollView * scrView;
for (UIView* view in scrollView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView class]]) {
        scrView = (UIScrollView *)view;
        [scrollView setContentSize:scrView.contentSize];

        break;
    }
}

[scrView removeConstraints:scrView.constraints];
scrView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
   constraintWithItem:scrView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
   toItem:scrollView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
   multiplier:1.0
   constant:0]];

[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
   constraintWithItem:scrView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
   toItem:scrollView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
   multiplier:1.0
   constant:0]];

[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
   constraintWithItem:scrView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
   toItem:scrollView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
   multiplier:1.0
   constant:0]];

[scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
   constraintWithItem:scrView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
   toItem:scrollView
   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
   multiplier:1.0
   constant:0]];
```

I am also sure that part of my problem is that I am trying to shoe horn new constraints into an app that mostly uses programmatically set frames from pre-iOS 7.

Can anybody point out my error from the code snippet I have posted or at least point me to a good resources for diagnosing the error myself?

Answer (score 0):

Do you add constraints only in this code snippet? 
The following message means that the scrollView has two conflicting constraints. One of them trying to set 50pt space to top, another trying to add 0pt space to top. And the system doesn't know which constraint to use.

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1899dd30 V:|-(50)-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:0x17ba9a00]   (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:0x17f88200 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1899e310 V:|-(0)-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView:0x17ba9a00]   (active, names: '|':UIScrollView:0x17f88200 )>"
```

Try to use

```
[scrollView layoutIfNeeded]
```

after removing constraints.

Comment: Based on your analysis of my error message I am guessing that I have mixed up my constraints because I have constraints on scrollView above these and meant for these to apply to a sub view of scrollView.

Comment: Actually, it should be right if you remove constraints. Check if constraints are removed and be sure to call                layoutIfNeeded after removing constraints.

Comment: Removing the constraints did not fix my issue but did not make it worse either.  I am still running into the issue that the initial rendering of the view has problems calculating constraints. Sometimes the constraints appear to spontaneously recalculate. other times I can simply rotate the phone and the recalculate. Either way on recalculation the view is rendered properly...

Comment: Ok, can you send me a whole file?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is something I am allowed to do.  Also I think the problem is that my constraints are spread over at least two files.  I am trying to pull everything together now.